# Neo4j Server Out of Memory using expandConfig

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Note**: please see the update towards the end.

I'm running this query against a graph that contains at least 300,000 nodes and after a while the memory usage on the server suddenly spikes to about 55Gb (killing the query). Typical safe usage is about 30Gb.

```
MATCH (d:Doc)
    WHERE d.id = <docId>
    MATCH (d)-[:pages]->(p:Page)
    CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(p, {
      relationshipFilter: "child",
      bfs: false
    })
    YIELD path
    WITH path, [r in relationships(path) | [r.order, id(r)]] as orders
    RETURN path
    ORDER BY orders
    SKIP 0 LIMIT 40000;
```

I can make it run for longer before failing by reducing the batch size, but ultimately it still fails.

This is the error I get in my C# code when the server becomes unresponsive.

> Connection with the server breaks due to IOException: Unexpected end
> of stream, unable to read expected data from the network connection
> Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and
> port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j
> server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has
> changed in Neo4j 4.0.

The database does recover after a while, but it's impossible for me to process all my records successfully.

The strange thing is I only get this behaviour in one of our databases. I can process the exact same set data in other Neo4j instances no problem (and no memory spike either) despite them all being provisioned the same way with the same config (they're running in Docker containers in Azure).

Can anyone suggest why? I'm using Neo4j Community 4.2.4 and APOC 4.2.0.5.

**Update**:
As Charchit pointed out, the way we are doing the ordering is very inefficient and in fact produced 11m database hits each time we ran the query. Removing this altogether fixed the memory spike on the server. However now our paths are not returned in the correct order.

We store the order on each relationship, and need to bring the paths back using that. In the example below, we need path (a)-(b)-(c), then (a)-(b)-(d) and finally (a)-(e).

[image: Order stored on relationships]

I found [an open issue](https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/issues/136) that sounds like it might help us in the future (not sure if it will support ordering though). In the meantime, is there a way of achieving this without the huge memory usage caused by our original implementation?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how it's spiking on one database and not on another, but I do see that you are computing `orders` as `[r in relationships(path) | [r.order, id(r)]]`, which will be a list of lists, and then you are using that for sorting. That is one thing that can consume a lot of memory. Are you sure you want to sort it like this?

Comment: To be honest I didn't write this query, so it's very interesting to me that you have identified this as a potential cause of the problem. I'm open to changing the query in any way that will make it more efficient/safe. We're using this query to write the tree structure to an XML file so as long as we can still achieve that, I can change it if you know of any better ways to do this.

Comment: I wonder if apoc.convert.toTree is something I should be looking at instead

Comment: Actually, just removing the ordering doesn't seem to have any negative consequences after just testing it out quickly. I'm sure there will be some downside, but I will now try this on this on the server and see if it stops the memory spike. That would be great if it does

Comment: Sure, just let me know. I believe you should gain something significant after removing the sort.

Comment: Hi, yes the memory spike is gone! The order of things is different though. If I profile the query, that sorting results in 11 million db hits! Can it be done another way?

Comment: I need some data to play around with. If you can add some temporary data, along with the expected output and what you are getting. I might be able to help you. Or if we can understand the sorting criteria, then we can simplify that as well.

Comment: I am going to come back to this (don't want you to think I'm ignoring it). But your observation about the sorting has prompted a bigger rewrite of the queries and restructure of our data. I'll write it up when I can (and probably clean up the comments too). In the meantime thanks for the tip, it really helped.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with an update, very grateful if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the graph, present in the picture, you can create a binary string, which will be a concatenation of the `order` properties of the relationships on the path, and use it for sorting, like this:

```
MATCH (a:A)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {
    relationshipFilter: "child",
    bfs: false,
})
YIELD path
WITH path, reduce(str = '', r in relationships(path) | str + toString(r.order) ) as orders
RETURN path
ORDER BY orders
SKIP 0 LIMIT 40000;
```

The graph was created by the following query:

```
MERGE (a:A)-[:child{order: 0}]->(b:B)-[:child{order: 0}]->(c:C)
MERGE (b)-[:child{order: 1}]->(d:D)
MERGE (a)-[:child{order:1}]->(e:E)
```

If you want to order using integer try this:

```
MATCH (a:A)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {
    relationshipFilter: "child",
    bfs: false,
})
YIELD path
WITH path, reduce(str = '', r in relationships(path) | str + toString(r.order) ) as orders
WITH path, toInteger(orders) as orders
RETURN path
ORDER BY orders
SKIP 0 LIMIT 40000;
```

This query should give you the most correct output:

```
MATCH (a:A)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {
    relationshipFilter: "child",
    bfs: false,
})
YIELD path
WITH path, reduce(str = '', r in relationships(path) | str + toString(r.order) ) as ordersAsString
WITH path, toInteger(ordersAsString) as ordersAsInt
RETURN path
ORDER BY ordersAsInt, ordersAsString
SKIP 0 LIMIT 40000;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been trying to get it to work and it largely does, but big chunks of the data are coming out in a different order compared with the original query (tried asc/desc), which I why I haven't replied until now. I wonder if the id(r) in the original query has something to do with it but still investigating...

Comment: Oh, update: it's because order 10, 11, 12 etc bumps those higher than they should be because when compared as a string, they come first, so I'm getting 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: What can be the distinct values of `r.order`? @Richard

Comment: It's always an integer but it can be any number because there can be any number of child nodes. I think if there's a way to convert orders to a list of integers rather than a list of strings, then that would probably work. I'm trying toIntegerList() but it doesn't seem to like that

Comment: I have added another query to convert orders to integers, but I am afraid, it might not work if there are two paths forming same integer. @Richard

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, there are lots of paths like 0, 00, 000 that all evaluate to the same integer and do not come back in the correct order. However you have given me plenty of ideas to get a perfect solution if I explore a bit more, and you answered my original question too so very grateful for your help, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It was a great question honestly. Haven't seen many of those in a while, so it was good thinking about this one.

Comment: @Richard I have added another query. Please check it out once.